# Setting the background of each grouping in a Itemcontrol based on the items

Tags: wpf, grouping, itemscontrol

I have an itemscontrol that I used grouping on for a bunch for large colored buttons. I would like the groups to have a slight background to them that match the button color, whatever it might be (it's randomly defined by the user, but only if all the buttons in the group are the same. If all the buttons in the group do not have the same color, the background of the group should be transparent.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate">
    <Button Margin="0,0,8,8" Padding="0" Style="{StaticResource TileButton}" Command="{Binding NavigateToContentsCommand}">
        <Grid Height="120" Width="271" Background="{Binding BackgroundBrush}">
            <Grid Margin="30">
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource MediumHeader}" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Button>
</DataTemplate>

<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ButtonPanel">
    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items.View}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ButtonPanel}">
    <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource DetailsTextBlock}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Rows="1" Columns="{Binding Items.View.Groups.Count}"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem">
                                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Border Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="{BINDING NOTSURE}" Opacity=".2"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0"/>
                                    <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="1"/>

                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

Where I put the Binding not sure is where I got lost on how to proceed. I'm not sure if I need to examine the children of the group or how to go about that. Anyone have any experience with this?
Thanks!

Comment: Study how to use `TemplatedParent` and `TemplateBinding`. I believe that's what you looking for.

Comment: @JonD what is the type of property that you group by?

Comment: It's a string. "Group"

Comment: Is this `Group` string convertible to `Brush`? Would you be able to write converter for it?

Comment: technically when checking all items (all Buttons in this case) against some condition, you have to loop through all the items and perform the check for each. Or somehow update the state every time an item has been changed. I mean you have to use some code behind here. Add some property to your ViewModel, such as called `AllButtonsHaveSameColor`. Try updating this property correctly and then in XAML code, you just need to add some Trigger listening to that property and set something you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the border to trigger a loaded event

```
<Border x:Name="ColorBorder" Loaded="ColorBorder_Loaded" Grid.RowSpan="2"  Opacity=".2"/>
```

Then add this event to loop through the items, if they exist.

```
private void ColorBorder_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Brush newBackgroundBrush = Brushes.Transparent;

    try
    {
        var grid = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent((DependencyObject)sender);
        GroupItem groupItem = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(grid) as GroupItem;

        CollectionViewGroup collectionViewGroup = (CollectionViewGroup)groupItem.Content;

        if (collectionViewGroup.ItemCount > 0)
        {
            WorkstationNavigationViewModel.NavigationLevelViewModel navigationLevelViewModel = (WorkstationNavigationViewModel.NavigationLevelViewModel)collectionViewGroup.Items[0];
            newBackgroundBrush = navigationLevelViewModel.BackgroundBrush;

            for (int index = 1; index < collectionViewGroup.ItemCount; index++)
            {
                navigationLevelViewModel = (WorkstationNavigationViewModel.NavigationLevelViewModel)collectionViewGroup.Items[index];
                if (navigationLevelViewModel.BackgroundBrush != newBackgroundBrush)
                {
                    newBackgroundBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        newBackgroundBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
    }
    finally
    {
        Border border = (Border)sender;
        border.Background = newBackgroundBrush;
    }

}
```